# Having trouble with signalR react typescript redux persist (backend dotnet 8) cannot get last message

Tags: reactjs, .net, typescript, redux

I am trying to implement a signalR communication service to my project. I have successfully made it subscribe to a conversation, but when going to the client component the last message is not updated before I hit refresh...this is a state ive been struggling with for days. my signalRService looks partly like this:

```
class SignalRService {
    public hubConnection: signalR.HubConnection | null = null;
    private connectionRef: signalR.HubConnection | null = null;
    private currentConversationId: string | null = null;
    private onMessageReceived: ((message: Message) => void) | null = null;
  
    public startConnection = (conversationId: string) => {
        this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl("http://192.168.1.80:5129/notificationhub", {
            skipNegotiation: true,
            transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets})
            
          //  .withAutomaticReconnect()
            .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Debug)
            .build();

        this.hubConnection.start().then(() => {
            console.log("SignalR connection started");
            this.registerOnMessageReceived(conversationId);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.error("Error while starting SignalR connection: " + err);
        });
    };



      public subscribeToConversation = async (conversationId: string) => {
        try {
            await this.hubConnection?.invoke("SubscribeToConversation", conversationId);
            console.log("Subscribed to conversation:", conversationId);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error("Error while subscribing to conversation:", err);
        }
    };

    public disconnect = () => {
        this.hubConnection?.stop()
            .then(() => {
                console.log("SignalR connection stopped");
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.error("Error while stopping SignalR connection: " + err);
            });
    };
    
    private registerOnMessageReceived = (conversationId: string) => {
        if (this.hubConnection && this.hubConnection.state === signalR.HubConnectionState.Connected) {
            this.hubConnection.on("ReceiveMessage", (message: Message) => {
                console.log("Received message:", message);
                // Dispatch action to update Redux store with the received message
                store.dispatch(addMessage(message));
                store.dispatch(setCurrentConversationId(conversationId))
                console.log('on message received conversationid', conversationId)
            });

            // Subscribe to messages for the specific conversation ID
            this.hubConnection.invoke("SubscribeToConversation", conversationId)
                .then(() => {
                    console.log("Subscribed to conversation:", conversationId);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.error("Error while subscribing to conversation:", err);
                });
        } else {
            console.error("SignalR connection is not in the 'Connected' state");
        }
    };
```

sendmessage component:

```
interface SendMessageProps {
    setCurrentConversationId: (conversationId: string) => void;
  }
  const SendMessage: React.FC<SendMessageProps> = ({ setCurrentConversationId }) => {
    const { conversationId } = useParams();
    const [messageContent, setMessageContent] = useState('');
  
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
    const messages = useSelector((state: { message: MessageState }) => state.message.messages);
    const currentConversationId = useSelector((state: { message: MessageState }) => state.message.conversationid);
    console.log(currentConversationId)

    useEffect(() => {
      setCurrentConversationId(conversationId ?? '');
    }, [conversationId, setCurrentConversationId]);
  
    const sendMessage = async () => {
      if (messageContent) {
        await signalRService.sendMessage(conversationId ?? '', messageContent);
  
        const myMessage: Message = {
          conversationId: conversationId ?? '',
          messageContent: messageContent,
          message: messageContent
        }
        dispatch(addMessage(myMessage));
        
      navigate('/messageList')
        persistor.flush().then(() => {
          console.log('Persisted state has been flushed to storage.');
      });
        console.log(addMessage(myMessage))
    
  
        setMessageContent('');
      }
    };
```

and the messageList component:

```
const MessageList: React.FC<MessageListProps> = ({ currentConversationId }) => {
  const messages = useSelector((state: { message: MessageState }) => state.message.messages);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    // Subscribe to the Redux store to get updates
    console.log("Messages from Redux store:", messages);
  }, [messages]); // Re-run effect when messages change

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriptionLogic = async () => {
      try {
        await signalRService.startConnection(currentConversationId ?? '');
        console.log('SignalR connection established');
        // Once the connection is established, you can subscribe to conversation here
        // For example:
        await signalRService.subscribeToConversation(currentConversationId ?? '');
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error while establishing SignalR connection:', error);
      }
    };

    subscriptionLogic();

    return () => {
      // Clean up SignalR connection when component unmounts
      signalRService.disconnect();
    };
  }, [currentConversationId]);
```

the last component is the one that does not update the message before refreshing the page with a hard reload...I do not want to use window.onLoad or anything. Anyone out there know something about this?

Im trying to integrate a real-time signalR communication service. Expecting messages to show immediately.